# LDAP query to return all users in a group

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I am writing an LDAP interface that, for a given group's `objectguid`, must return a list of all users in those groups along with the user's SID.

For a given group's `objectguid` the code below returns the users in that group.  However they are all in the form...

```
CN=Chad Hutchins,OU=Contractors,DC=RM,DC=LOCAL
```

... but I need the user's SID vs. the above string.  Is there a way to obtain a user's SID starting from a group and querying for all users in that group?

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

public void GetUsers(Guid groupId, string domain, string username, string password)
{
    var rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
    rootEntry.Username = username;
    rootEntry.Password = password;

    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);
    searcher.Filter = @"(objectguid=" + ConvertGuidToOctectString(groupId) + ")";

    var groupResult = searcher.FindOne();
    foreach (DictionaryEntry prop in groupResult.Properties)
    {
        var key = (string)prop.Key;

        switch (key)
        {
            case "member":
                foreach (string name in groupResult.Properties[key])
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private string ConvertGuidToOctectString(Guid guid)
{
    var byteGuid = guid.ToByteArray();
    var queryGuid = string.Empty;
    foreach (var b in byteGuid)
    {
        queryGuid += @"\" + b.ToString("x2");
    }
    return queryGuid;
}
```

Comment: Can you use `AccountManagement` class? It will be really easy to obtain the user `SID`. If not, then what you can do is store all `DistinguishedName` of all members inside list of strings and then do a search for users by their DN and then you can retrieve the `SIDs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options on how to retrieve user `SIDs` from a particular `group`.

1. Use `GroupPrincipal` in `AccountManagement` namepsace.

   ```
   public static List<string> GetUsersFromGroupByGroupID(string ID)
   {
       using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com")
       {
           using (GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Guid, ID))
           {
               if (group != null)
               {
                   List<string> memberSIDs = new List<string>();
                   var members = group.GetMembers(true);
                   foreach(var member in members)
                   {
                       memberSIDs.Add(member.Sid.ToString());
                   }
                   return memberSIDs;
               }
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
2. You can store the `DistinguishedName` of all the users from your query into a `List<string>` and then do a look up for user `SID` using `UserPrincipal` class.

   ```
   public static List<string> GetUserSIDs(List<string>userDNs)
   {
       List<string> userSIDs = new List<string>();
       using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
       {
           foreach(string userDN in userDNs)
           {
               using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, userDN))
               {
                   if (user != null)
                   {
                       userSIDs.Add(user.Sid.ToString());
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return userSIDs;
   }
   ```
3. And the last option you can still get the list of `DistiniguishedName` from you query and still use `DirectoryEntry`

   ```
   using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://userDistinguishedName")
   {
       var userSID = entry.Properties["objectSID"][0];
   }
   ```

NOTE* in this case `userSID` will be returned as `byte[] array`.